# Running a ARM64 Ubuntu install with QEMU on Intel based Mac Book Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, virtualization, intel

I am trying to install a ARM64 ubuntu 22.04 iso with QEMU on an Intel based Mac Book Pro 2019 with the following:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 8G \
-smp 6 \
-cdrom ./ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso  \
-drive file=mydisk2.qcow3,if=virtio \
-vga std \
-display default,show-cursor=on \
-usb \
-device usb-tablet \
-cpu host \
-machine type=q35,accel=hvf
```

However, I receive the following error message:

[image]

Comment: I assume you have your reason to use an ARM Linux instead of an x86 version. But more to the point: are the paths to the CD image and the drive correct, are the files readable by the user running QEMU? Also, how did you download the ISO?

Comment: Yes there is a reason.  The paths to the CD image and the drive are both correct, and they are both readable by the user running QEMU.  I even tried running as the root user and it gives me the same error.  When I try running it with a x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04 image it doesn't give me this error.

Comment: Does this help? http://zhiyisun.github.io/2016/02/04/Install-Ubuntu-1510-ARM64-Inside-of-Qemu.html

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run software written for the ARM64 architecture via a program that emulates (or virtualizes) the x86_64 architecture. That won't work as they are different architectures.

What to do from here depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.

A common problem is that people mixup ARM64 with AMD64. AMD64 is another name for x86_64. So you might have read instructions that details AMD64, and then downloaded an ARM64 Linux distribution instead of the Intel version that you really needed.

If you want this to be a performant virtual machine, then you need to download an Intel x86_64 Linux distribution.

On the other hand, if you actually have a very specific need to run ARM64 software on your machine (for example if you want to run a program only available for ARM64) - then you would instead need to install a different variant of QEMU. You would want to use the `qemu-system-aarch64` program instead.

Note that this will run Linux much slower - so don't do it unless you have a very specific need for it.

Comment: Got it, I was running x86_64 version of QEMU.  I've switched over to qemu-system-aarch64, but I am still experiencing some difficulties this time with the arguments that you have to pass to it.