# QEMU arm on a Intel macOS

Tags: macos, intel

I am trying to run a Ubuntu 22.04 ARM64 image on a Intel Mac with the following QEMU command:

```
qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -machine type=virt \
  -m 4G \
  -display default,show-cursor=on \
  -usb \
  -smp 2 \
  -cdrom ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso \
  -drive file=test.qcow2,if=virtio
```

It runs QEMU, but I just get a boot screen that looks like this as opposed to fully booting into the image.

[image]

Comment: Cross posting isn't allowed on the SE network.  You've got this particular topic of virtualization and emulation posted multiple times  on different sites - **what exactly are you trying to accomplish?**

Comment: @Allan: The OP implanted [jksoegaard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463085/running-a-arm64-ubuntu-install-with-qemu-on-intel-based-mac-book-pro/463102#463102) given in the [earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463085/running-a-arm64-ubuntu-install-with-qemu-on-intel-based-mac-book-pro). The OP now has a new question which can not be fixed using that answer. I do not see how this new question can be a duplicate of the earlier question.

Comment: they are both about booting an ARM version of Ubuntu running on Apple Intel via QEMU.  Are we going to have a separate question for each and every step the OP encounters?  There's a reasonable expectation, that at a minimum, the OP  *show what research was done* and up to now, we haven't seen any @DavidAnderson

Comment: Noone is saying that we need a seperate question for each and every step. However, the first question was one that other people could also easily have - i.e. a misunderstanding between AMD64 and ARM64. The second question is a more straight-forward "I'm using the right tools for the job, but somehow this isn't working".

Comment: There seems to be questions (many with answers) at AskUbuntu regarding running ARM Ubuntu in QEMU on Intel Ubuntu hosts. The OP may have better luck by first installing Ubuntu on the Intel Mac as the host.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here seems to be that you're missing the EFI firmware. An ARM machine cannot boot anything by "itself" really, you need a loader like what the EFI firmware will give you.

You specify the location of the EFI firmware by adding a `-bios` parameter to your qemu command. Depending on where you installed qemu from, you'll find the EFI code in a file named something like "edk2-aarch64-code.fd".

You'll also want to specify your requirements for the kind of CPU that qemu should emulate. For example `-cpu max`.

Comment: So I tried the bios argument with edk2-aarch64-code.fd and I still get the same screen, here is my command:

sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
  -bios edk2-aarch64-code.fd \
  -machine virt,gic-version=max \
  -m 512M \
  -cpu max \
  -smp 4 \
  -netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:0-:22 \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet \
  -drive file=ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-arm64.iso,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback \
  -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 \
  -drive file=test.img,format=raw

Comment: Do you actually have the edk2-aarch64-code.fd file in the current directory where you are running that command?